# How do I install Jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm using a MacOS, and I'm trying to run Jupyterhub but it's not working. When I type: "sudo jupyterhub", the following shows up:

```
[I 2018-06-14 13:05:48.216 JupyterHub app:834] Loading cookie_secret from /Users/Robert/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[W 2018-06-14 13:05:48.365 JupyterHub app:955] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2018-06-14 13:05:48.365 JupyterHub app:956] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2018-06-14 13:05:48.366 JupyterHub app:983] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[I 2018-06-14 13:05:48.403 JupyterHub app:1528] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
[W 2018-06-14 13:05:48.405 JupyterHub proxy:415] 
Generating CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN. Restarting the Hub will require restarting the proxy.
    Set CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN env or JupyterHub.proxy_auth_token config to avoid this message.

[W 2018-06-14 13:05:48.405 JupyterHub proxy:456] Running JupyterHub without SSL.  I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else...
[I 2018-06-14 13:05:48.405 JupyterHub proxy:458] Starting proxy @ http://*:8000/
[E 2018-06-14 13:05:48.419 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to 34-36-3b-75-b6-de.**(CENSORED)** [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-06-14 13:05:48.452 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to 34-36-3b-75-b6-de.**(CENSORED)** [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-06-14 13:05:48.784 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to 34-36-3b-75-b6-de.**(CENSORED)** [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
13:05:49.178 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxying http://*:8000 to (no default)
13:05:49.183 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/routes
13:05:49.185 - error: [ConfigProxy] Uncaught Exception Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(/Users/Robert/anaconda3/lib/node_modules/configurable-http-proxy/bin/configurable-http-proxy:253:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
13:05:49.187 - error: [ConfigProxy] Uncaught Exception Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8001
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1517:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at Immediate._tickCallback [as _onImmediate] 
(internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
[E 2018-06-14 13:05:49.377 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to 34-36-3b-75-b6-de.**(CENSORED)** [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
[E 2018-06-14 13:05:49.481 JupyterHub utils:47] Unexpected error connecting to 34-36-3b-75-b6-de.**(CENSORED)** [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    [C 2018-06-14 13:05:49.482 JupyterHub app:1535] Failed to start proxy
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Robert/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1533, in start
    yield self.proxy.start()
      File "/Users/Robert/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/proxy.py", line 482, in start
    _check_process()
      File "/Users/Robert/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterhub/proxy.py", line 478, in _check_process
    raise e
    RuntimeError: Proxy failed to start with exit code 0
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. Did I forget to install a file? Am I not the admin? Plz help ;(

Comment: Why are you running jupyterhub on your mac? It is meant to be run on servers. You can just use `jupyterlab` or `jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 0):

It seems Jupyter is trying to use port 8000 as is default, but it is already in use. First, make sure Jupyter Hub isn't already running somewhere else. If it is not, another service might be using that port on your computer already. Try running `sudo jupyterhub --port=8080` to run it on port 8080 instead.